# How to exclude certain elements from printing?

Tags: python

Is there a way to make a print only include something dependent on an if statement like so:

```
for i in list_of_numbers:
    print(f"Hello {i}" if i in range(100))
```

If I enter that it expects an else but, I don't want to print anything if the if statement is not True, python forces this:

```
print(f"Hello {i}" if i in range(100) else '')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complex one-liner problem, if you are interested in it, you can do something like this:

```
print(*(f"Hello {i}" for i in list_of_numbers if i in range(100)),sep="\n")
```

Comment: It's not the most readable code, you can push it into multiple lines but Python one liners are the best!

Answer (score 0):

Your second example will work just fine if you just remove the implied newline character.

```
print(f"Hello {i}" if i in range(100) else '', end='')
```

Now it prints nothing when `i in range(100)` evaluates to false.